# Windows 10 Upgrade tool fails 0x8007001F-0x30000D

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, hard-drive, windows-10-upgrade

I ran into the error code `0x8007001F-0x30000D` when trying to update from Windows 7 to Windows 10.
Many articles on the web point out, that the problem occured due to moving the /Users folder to another drive.
When installing Windowns 7 I set up my /Users on another hard drive (`E:\`). My hard drive mounted on `E:` has a capacity of 2 TB, while my `C:` drive has 256 GB. My /Users folder has used up 542 GB, so moving back to `C:/` and performing the update won't work.
Is there another option to make the update work?

Comment: I would try backing up the contents of the USERS folder and making the folder small enough to do the update. After Windows 10 is installed, go to the USERS folder and locate whatever data on the large drive. You may find a 256 GB main drive too limiting

Comment: My idea when setting up my computer was to have windows run on an SSD and store my data on a bigger HDD. But yes, I'm considiering the option of removing some data, but that won't solve the problem in the long run

Comment: Making the USERS folder much smaller will help. Make sure the machine Drivers are all up to date before starting the upgrade. Remove any third party Anti Virus apps and then try again.

Comment: Suggestions here>>>>>https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/windows-update-error-0x8007001f.html